# Code first migration for a SQL Server CE database file

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` is used. The database that is stored within SQL Server Express is updated.

When opening a local stored `.sdf` file (SQL Server CE database) with a valid path and file name, this file is not updated.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DTDataContext, Configuration>()); 
var connection = DTDataContext.GetConnectionSqlServerCE40(fullPathName);

dataBaseContext = new DTDataContext(connection, true);
dataBaseContext.Database.Initialize(true);
```

The `MigrationHistory` entries will be made in SQL Server Express and not in the local SQL Server CE database file.

What would be the easiest way to update a local SQL Server CE database file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few experiments, an adequate solution was found (which fits for my purpose).

The question was focused about the old sdf(s) that were previously written but with an older model in contrast to the code.
I decided not to migrate old files (which are applied as a kind of backups).
Only reading will be made within those files. Obviously, it is possible that newer sdf(s) will be read once in the future but that's not a big deal.
Before reading stuff of an entity that could maybe not exist (in a sdf), it will be checked via `SqlQuery` and `count(*)`.

```
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage( "Microsoft.Design", "CA1031:DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes" )]
        private bool TestIfTableExists( string tableName, DTDataContext dataContext )
        {
            try
            {
                int cnt = dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>( "select count(*) from " + tableName ).First();
                return cnt > 0;
            }
            catch( Exception ex ) { /*available SqlCeException assembly does not fit --- table does not exist*/ return false; }
        }
```

btw When using SqlCeException (v3.5), which could be provided as a reference via the assembly search, the above situation would fail (=unhandled exception!). Have not tested it with v4 because I wanna avoid a 'manual' reference because it must be checked in (no need for any path problems with other workstations).

Concerning writing a sdf:
When writing a new sdf with the current model, this is not a problem at all.

[Database.CreateIfNotExists()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.createifnotexists%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) was applied.

In my case, updating a sdf was not necessary --- and a quick solution for that was not found.